# Laptop kicks other users off the wifi when it connects, then gets disconnected itself

Tags: linux, networking, dhcp, wireless-networking

I've got an Acer Aspire One running Linux. When I connect to my building's wifi, everything seems fine for a short period of time (I can google a few things or start downloading an Apt package), but then other devices on the network lose their IP addresses. Shortly after that, my computer also gets disconected. My computer is set to use DHCP.

What causes this, and do you know how it could be fixed? Am I causing a broadcast storm?

Comment: Check router for static IP settings.

Comment: I do not have access to the router.

Comment: @DKNUCKLES Thank you. I wasn't sure since I thought it equally likely that it was a router problem as that it was a problem with just my settings. I'm not sure if my laptop is the only machine that causes this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Probably something is screwed up with your laptop's network setup. Check if you might be running a [rogue DHCP server](https://serverfault.com/questions/8526/how-do-i-find-if-there-is-a-rogue-dhcp-server-on-my-network) or have set up bridging (use `ifconfig` to check for bridge intrerfaces) in an unhealthy way.

Comment: Running an arp-proxy may cause similar effects as well.

Comment: I don't have any bridge interfaces. I don't remember setting up a dhcp server ever.. it's a fairly freshly wiped Ubuntu installation.  Could my NIC be bad?

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure there is no misconfiguration, try connecting to the network from a Linux live system and see if it still happens.

If it does, you might want to sniff packets on your network using `tcpdump` or Wireshark and watch for something unusual coming from/going to your host. If possible, you might also want to try another NIC (connected through USB). Besides the NIC the driver or the firmware you are currently using could also be faulty and cause misbehavior on the network.

Comment: This is a great idea. I don't own an external or a large enough USB drive at the moment, but I will be sure to give this a try. Thank you